# Arithmetic operation around javascript alert() function

Tags: javascript, xss

I have been practicing some hacking skills using the [portswigger academy](https://portswigger.net/web-security/), and in one of the labs there was a search engine which had a reflected XXS vulnerability.

Entering the string `foo` in the search engine produced this source code:

```
<section class="blog-header">
<h1>0 search results for 'foo'</h1>
</section>
```

The solution to the lab was to enter `'-alert(1)-'`  the below source code produced:

```
<section class="blog-header">
<h1>0 search results for '&apos;-alert(1)-&apos;'</h1>
</section>
```

Can someone explain why we have to insert the `-` arithmetic operation? How does `-` work with JavaScript except for the subtraction operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't seem right... I don't see any JS execution in your example! The alert is just part of the text.

But, if this is used elsewhere, especially in server-generated Javascript code, then it would make sense. Because `var x = 'foo'` would become `var x = '' - alert(1) - ''`, which indeed would subtract the result of `alert(1)` (which is `undefined`) from an empty string, but it would also work with `+` or anything else, because it's just in order to escape from the string and evaluate the alert as code. The `x` variable would contain garbage but you would have achieved your result already - executing code.

Answer (score 0):

> How does - work with JavaScript except for the subtraction operation?

The only things `-` does outside of strings or template literals (where it's just the `-` character) are:

- Subtraction (the binary operator, `a - b`)
- Negation (the unary operator, `-a`)
- In a regular expression literal, it denotes a range in a character class (`/[A-F0-9]/i` for hex, for instance).

In what you've quoted, the `-` is just a character in a string. There's no successful XSS attack there. (Perhaps it was elsewhere on the site.)